# UIButton Call in separate Class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am using an expandable tableView. One of the cells will be used for a button to open a URL link in safari. The button IBOulet is in WebsiteCell class and the data and view controller are in Detail View.

In the Detail View class I have an error while trying to call the button where it says `websiteCell.venueURL(UIButton)`. The error says 'Extra Argument in call'.

What should be here instead of UIButton?

WebsiteCell Class

```
class WebsiteCell: UITableViewCell {



@IBAction func venueURL(sender: UIButton) {


}
```

Detail View Class

```
else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        let websiteCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("websiteCell") as! WebsiteCell

        let venueURL = venues!["URL"] as! String



        websiteCell.venueURL(UIButton){
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: venueURL)!)



        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the button in storyboard to a prototype cell of type websiteCell. Then you can link this button to your websiteCell class as an @IBAction, and the code to open the URL should be placed in the IBAction.

```
class WebsiteCell: UITableViewCell {

    var venueURL: String?

    @IBAction func venueURL(sender: UIButton) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: venueURL)!)
    }

}
```

Then, your cellForRowAtIndexPath method will look like this:

```
else if indexPath.row == 3 {

    let websiteCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("websiteCell") as! WebsiteCell

    websiteCell.venueURL = //url here

    return websiteCell

}
```